# Substr_replace doesn't process accents properly

Tags: php

```
$accents = array(    'Š'=>'S', 'š'=>'s', 'Ž'=>'Z', 'ž'=>'z', 'À'=>'A', 'Á'=>'A', 'Â'=>'A', 'Ã'=>'A', 'Ä'=>'A', 'Å'=>'A', 'Æ'=>'A', 'Ç'=>'C', 'È'=>'E', 'É'=>'E',
                        'Ê'=>'E', 'Ë'=>'E', 'Ì'=>'I', 'Í'=>'I', 'Î'=>'I', 'Ï'=>'I', 'Ñ'=>'N', 'Ò'=>'O', 'Ó'=>'O', 'Ô'=>'O', 'Õ'=>'O', 'Ö'=>'O', 'Ø'=>'O', 'Ù'=>'U',
                        'Ú'=>'U', 'Û'=>'U', 'Ü'=>'U', 'Ý'=>'Y', 'Þ'=>'B', 'ß'=>'Ss', 'à'=>'a', 'á'=>'a', 'â'=>'a', 'ã'=>'a', 'ä'=>'a', 'å'=>'a', 'æ'=>'a', 'ç'=>'c',
                        'è'=>'e', 'é'=>'e', 'ê'=>'e', 'ë'=>'e', 'ì'=>'i', 'í'=>'i', 'î'=>'i', 'ï'=>'i', 'ð'=>'o', 'ñ'=>'n', 'ò'=>'o', 'ó'=>'o', 'ô'=>'o', 'õ'=>'o',
                        'ö'=>'o', 'ø'=>'o', 'ù'=>'u', 'ú'=>'u', 'û'=>'u', 'ý'=>'y', 'þ'=>'b', 'ÿ'=>'y' );
$nameNoAccents = strtr( $row['name'], $accents );
$query = $_GET['query'];
$name = $row['name'];
$pos = stripos($name, $query);
$change = substr($nameNoAccents, $pos, strlen($query));
$name = substr_replace($name, "<b>$change</b>", $pos, strlen($query));
```

I'm having issues with replacing text containing accents as part of an auto-complete system. The query is what's inputted in the auto-complete text input, while the $row['name'] variable represents one the values it matches from a MySQL database.

For example:

$query = Montre

$row['name'] = Montréal

The problem is, while I would expect $name to be "**Montré**al", that's not quite what happens, instead I get "**Montre**�al" with the � sitting outside the bold tag.

I'm wondering if this has to do with the encoding, and I don't know if substr_replace supports multibyte.

Answer (score 0):

You're right about it having to do with the encoding. Some PHP functions don't support multibyte characters, and in these cases, their [multibyte counterparts](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) have to be used.

Now, as for your code there are two issues:

```
$pos = stripos($name, $query);
```

You want to search for the query position inside the string with no accents, so change `$name` to `$nameNoAccents`.

```
$change = substr($nameNoAccents, $pos, strlen($query));
```

Here you actually want to use `$name` instead of `$nameNoAccents`, since you want to replace the string with the accents. Also, `substr` is actually not multibyte safe. Use `mb_substr` instead.

So the final result would look like this:

```
$nameNoAccents = strtr( $row['name'], $accents );
$query = $_GET['query'];
$name = $row['name'];
$pos = stripos($nameNoAccents, $query);
$change = mb_substr($name, $pos, strlen($query));
$name = substr_replace($nameNoAccents, "<b>$change</b>", $pos, strlen($query));
```